# Disable file chunking with CRACO

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, craco

I am trying to figure out how to use CRACO (https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco) to disable file chunking in create react app.

I have created the following craco.config.js:

```js
// craco.config.js
module.exports = {
  output: {
    fileName: 'static/js/bundle.js',
  },
}
```

But it doesn't have any effect.  What should the config look like to disable file chunking in CRA with CRACO?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EDIT: To disable chunking completely I believe this might do it.
Source: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5306#issuecomment-650737697

```
// craco.config.js
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: {
      optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: false,
        splitChunks: {
          chunks(chunk) {
            return false
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

---

ORIGNIAL:
Maybe [this](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/issues/155#issuecomment-619604951) could help?

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: {
      output: {
        filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
      },
      optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: false,
        splitChunks: {
          chunks: 'all',
          cacheGroups: {
            default: false,
            vendors: false,
            // vendor chunk
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: require('craco-plugin-scoped-css'),
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: Thanks I now have a main bundle file but I am still getting 1 chunk file `1.hash.chunk.js`.  Any way to find out what this is from?

Comment: @Guerrilla I've updated the answer with a new solution, please let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks, the edit still gave one chunk file but reading the linked github thread had answer that this file is being created by reportWebVitals.  Commenting that out results in a single bundle file

Comment: @Guerrilla nice one!

Comment: amazeballs!  You saved my bacon. AFAICT craco isn't updating the serviceworker __WB_MANIFEST  valriable with more than one chunk!

Comment: actually this solution continues to have the wrong values for WB_MANIFEST

Answer (score 0):

follow the new solution in the [github comments](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5306#issuecomment-1426637113). I use this in my **craco.config.cjs**:

```json
module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: {
      plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
          maxChunks: 1,
        })
      ]
    }
  },
  plugins: [{ plugin: CracoEsbuildPlugin }]
};
```

It works at `@craco/craco 7.0.0`